# C# Contextmenu jumping if populated on Popup event

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I have a MenuItem that contains all files in a specific folder.

The menuitem is populated on its own Popup event (using `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`), but if it is too close to the lower right corner of the screen (or so it seems), it will jump higher up on the screen while being populated.

If I populate it before the Popup event is raised, the menu item will open in the usual position.

I must populate it on the popup event to keep the contents of the folder up-to-date.

Why does the menu item move if it is populated on the Popup event, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Have you seen this behavior on a variety of browsers?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify enough. It is C# in Windows Applications. The contextmenu is connected to a tray icon (which means it will be in the lower right corner of the screen most of the time, thus making this a annoying problem).

Comment: Can you add some sample code to show the problem?  When I try it here, it works properly as far as I can tell.  There's no screen update occurring while the context menu is populated, and the menu doesn't appear until the Popup handler has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this a little, I'm not sure updating the menu at popup time is the best approach.  Build the menu once at startup, and use a FileSystemWatcher (or a few if there are different locations) to notify you of changes, and update the menu as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a DataGridView.

I used pop-up menu to let the user choose from few most typical inputs when filling up the grid. And depending on what was in the cell clicked, options would be a bit different.
I had this context menu jumping and blinking.
I tried several approaches, what I finally did was

**1.** resetting the **ContextMenu** property of my **DataGridView** (I mean I just zeroed this property)

**2.** populating the menu in DataGridView's **CellMouseDown event** instead of the context menu's **Opening event**

**3.** after populating it (still in CellMouseDown), simply assigning this menu to this particular cell

```
myDataGridView[column, row].ContextMenuStrip = myPopUpMenu;
```

And that's it. Worked fine, without any undesired visual phenomena ;).